# Should I refresh list::iterator when the list reallocates memory?

Tags: c++, list, stl, iterator

Imagine a railway line. We have some stations and some sections where the train travels with reduced speed (reduspeeds). These sections can contain stations. I need to split the sections to parts not containing stations.

E.g.: From the 1500th m to the 3500th m of the line, the train can travel with only 40 km/h. I have two stations at 2000 m and 3000 m. In this case, I need to have 3 sections: 1500m - 2000m, 2000m-3000m and 3000m-3500m.

So i coly my original reduspeed sections into a std::list, amd my while(for()) double loop goes through it and finds out whether it has inner stations.
If one has:

1. the function splits it into two parts (temp_speed_section_1 and 2)
2. inserts these parts before the actual reduspeed_section in the list
3. erases the original reduspeed_section
4. moves the iterator 2 positions back (which should be the object stored in temp_speed_section_1)
5. continues the search with the newly inserted reduspeed_section (because the original section can have more stations in it)

My code:

```
namespace split
{
/** \brief  Finds reduspeed sections (left) with inner station(s) and splits them into equivalent reduspeed sections without inner stations
 *
 * \param   const &reduspeeds_left  the origial vector of reduspeeds
 * \param   const &stations         the stations of the line
 * \return  &split_reduspeeds       the list to hold the new split and unchanged reduspeed sections
 *
 */

    bool FindOverhangingReduspeedSectionsLeft(std::vector <speed_section> const &reduspeeds_left, std::vector <station> const &stations,
                                                std::list <speed_section> &split_reduspeeds)
    {
        std::copy(reduspeeds_left.begin(), reduspeeds_left.end(),  std::back_inserter(split_reduspeeds));
        std::list<speed_section>::iterator iter_list_reduspeeds = split_reduspeeds.begin();
        int items_stations = stations.size();
        speed_section temp_speed_section_1;
        speed_section temp_speed_section_2;

        while(iter_list_reduspeeds != split_reduspeeds.end())
        {
label_1:
            for (int j=0; j<items_stations; j++)
            {

                if (iter_list_reduspeeds->its_start < stations[j].its_left_station  &&  stations[j].its_left_station < iter_list_reduspeeds->its_end)
                {
                    temp_speed_section_1.its_start = iter_list_reduspeeds->its_start;
                    temp_speed_section_1.its_end = stations[j].its_left_station;
                    temp_speed_section_1.its_speed = iter_list_reduspeeds->its_speed;

                    temp_speed_section_2.its_start = stations[j].its_left_station;
                    temp_speed_section_2.its_end = iter_list_reduspeeds->its_end;
                    temp_speed_section_2.its_speed = iter_list_reduspeeds->its_speed;

                    split_reduspeeds.insert(iter_list_reduspeeds, temp_speed_section_1);
                    split_reduspeeds.insert(iter_list_reduspeeds, temp_speed_section_2);

                    split_reduspeeds.erase(iter_list_reduspeeds);
                    /// In order to avoid the need for sorted "stations" vector/list, iterator goes to the first part of the actual reduspeed
                    --iter_list_reduspeeds;
                    --iter_list_reduspeeds;

                    goto label_1;
                }
            }

            ++iter_list_reduspeeds;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

So the function finds a resduspeed section with a station, it splits it into two parts, inserts them into the list, erases the original and repositions the iterator. At this point, the iterator point to a speed_section object (correctly), but the member variables of this object have some random values. The while loop than crashes next time when it tries to insert a new object into the list.

I tryed but faild to find out what is the problem. Is it possible that when I insert the new values into the list, it reallocates memory but the iterator cant "refresh" itself, or something like that?

Comment: Also replace `if` with `while` and remove `goto`.

Comment: It's not the lists fault; it's not reallocating memory (vector _does_ reallocate memory).. _You_ are erasing an element, and that invalidates that specific iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::list::erase` invalidates the given iterator, you need store its result in `iter_list_reduspeeds`:

```
iter_list_reduspeeds = split_reduspeeds.erase(iter_list_reduspeeds);
std::advance(iter_list_reduspeeds, -2);
```